# angular.js - decimal numbers in European notation

Tags: angularjs, format, decimal

In Angular you can use the currency filter to format a number, like like this:

```
{{service.price | currency: "€ "}}
```

the standard output is

```
€ #,##0.00
```

How can the output be:

```
€ #.##0,00
```

(European notation)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Angular supports `i18n` Standard for location | globalization | internationalization.  When it comes to number formatting Angular relies on `$locale` service and more specifically on the property `NUMBER_FORMATS`.

The currency symbol by itself will not change the numbering formatting unless you change the 'location'.

Here is the list of locations currently supported by angular:

http://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-i18n/

Here is an example on how to support [german locale](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n):

```
<html ng-app>
 <head>

   <script src="angular.js"></script>
   <script src="i18n/angular-locale_de-de.js"></script>

 </head>
</html>
```

If you want to dig more into it you can search for `NUMBER_FORMATS` in any of the CDNs provided above and you will find what angular will use to format your numbers, this is an example:

```
"NUMBER_FORMATS": {
    "CURRENCY_SYM": "\u20ac",
    "DECIMAL_SEP": ",",
    "GROUP_SEP": ".",
...
```