# Change input value according to locale in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, locale

I have a scenerio in which I have to change the number (that user puts in input field) according to its locale format. And I want that change to reflect in the HTML right away.

Like if user enter a number like 23.4 so it should change straight away to 23,4 in the **ng-model** and html view as well.

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.newPlayer.weight" ng-class="{'active' : vm.newPlayer.weight}">
```

This is the input field I have.

Comment: sounds like an interesting piece of code.  what part of it are you having trouble with?

Comment: can you able to post your code

Comment: Not entirely clear what the requirements are honestly but check out $parsers/$formatters in ngModel they allow you to modify the view or stored value (parsers parse from the view to the model, formatters format from the model to the view)

Comment: What i want is when user type something in input field it will convert to its locale format right away in the view and model.

Comment: Try to use `$parsers` as mentioned @shaunhusain.

Comment: Does it help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409939/angular-js-decimal-numbers-in-european-notation

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make use of watch and do the required things on the value change.

Here is a sample fiddle which may help you http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/jmf6kL3n/

```
$scope.myName = "";
$scope.greeting = "h";
$scope.$watch("myName", function (newValue, oldValue) {
   //some custom code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining your ng-model, watch and [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) you can achieve this. That is, bind input to ng-model, watch for changes in your component and then use toLocaleString to covert number to you desired locale. Us, German and other format are also available.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString